# I want to set a value including BorderRadius.circular as the default value of the argument of the constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I have defined a custom widget for ElevatedButton, and I want to make the shape field optional as shown below and use the initial value when no value is passed, but when I write it as above, the following error occurs. ..

```
class GradientElevatedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  GradientElevatedButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.child,
    required this.colors,
    this.shape = RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),//←here
    ),
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final void Function() onPressed;
  final List<Color> colors;
  final OutlinedBorder shape;
```

```
//error
The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.
```

Maybe it means that the BorderRadius.circular constructor is not const,

How should I write if I want to use the following OutlinedBorder as the default value?
RoundedRectangleBorder (
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular (30),
)

Comment: Like it says, you can only use a `const` value as a default value and `BorderRadius.circular` doesn't appear to be a `const` constructor. That said, `BorderRadius.all` does appear to be a `const` constructor. You should be able to do something like `this.shape = const RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BorderRadius.circular` is not a `const` constructor, so you cannot use it as a default value of a `const` constructor.

However, if you look at the implementation:

```dart
/// Creates a border radius where all radii are [Radius.circular(radius)].
BorderRadius.circular(double radius) : this.all(
  Radius.circular(radius),
);
```

It uses `BorderRadius.all` and `Radius.circular` and both of them are `const` constructor.

So you can replace

```dart
BorderRadius.circular(shape)
```

with

```dart
BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))
```

Here is your updated code sample:

```dart
class GradientElevatedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  GradientElevatedButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.child,
    required this.colors,
    this.shape = const RoundedRectangleBorder( // <- Don't forget the const keyword
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),//←here
    ),
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final void Function() onPressed;
  final List<Color> colors;
  final OutlinedBorder shape;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not what you want, but sometime it helps others.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientElevatedbutton extends StatelessWidget {
  const GradientElevatedbutton({
    Key? key,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.child,
    required this.colors,
    this.shape = 30,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final void Function() onPressed;
  final List<Color> colors;
  final double shape;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(shape),
        ),
      ),
      child: Text('click'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, we can do that as well.
Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code:

```
this.shape = RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
```

must be change to:

```
this.shape = const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Yes, as you say, I got an error when I added the const keyword to the RoundedRectangleBorder.

After all, I think the cause is that BorderRadius.circular (30) is not const.